# Android photo orientation sensor

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer

I have my app where I use photos from cam or gallery, if I take photo from gallery it can be turned upside down. How can I make correct photo orientation?

Comment: The case was with me also.While clicking photo handle camera in the Landscape position,the result you'll get in the portrait position

Comment: Now I understood a little more about problem. When I take photo from gallary, I will have a correct position, but when took photo from cam, it came in Landscape position cause its cam params. I think, I should turn bitmap before to send to CROP activity

Comment: rotate programatically to portrait mode before setting bitmap

Comment: Check out my answer here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971319/image-orientation-android/32747566#32747566